# Собственная функция MySubstring

Tags: c#

Я решил написать собственую функцию MySubstring. Но я не уверен что правильно все  сделал + в меине выдает ошибку  что я не могу так  записывать

```
string mySubstring = MySubstring(str1, 3, 3);
```

Код:

```
string MySubstring(string str, int startIndex, int length)
{
    string temp = System.String.Empty;
    for (int index = 0; index < str.Length; ++index)
    {
       if (str[index] == startIndex)
       {
          for (int j = 0; j < length; ++j)
          {
             temp += str[index];
          }
       }
    }
    return temp;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string str1 = "I like it like that";
   string mySubstring = MySubstring(str1, 3, 3);
   System.Console.WriteLine(mySubstring);
}
```

Comment: Добавьте `static` к своей функции.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо,  но теперь другая проблема в консольничего не выводится и я не  знаю  праильно ли я написал функцию

Comment: Вы наступаете на одни и те же грабли: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/930455/218063

Comment: `temp += str[index+j];`

Comment: `str[index] == startIndex` — это выглядит странно, потому что `str[index]` — это символ, который находится в позиции `index` в строке. Ну и вложенный цикл не нужен, достаточно одного цикла от 0 до length

Comment: но и вы же понимаете, что это `temp += str[index+j];` будет каждый раз создавать новую строку? То есть эффективности тут нет никакой.

Comment: @tym32167 а как сделать чтобы была ефективность?

Comment: @АндрейNOP не совсем понял как с одним фором сделать. мне же надо по всему стрингу пройтись...

Comment: Зачем вам проходить по всей строке, если вы можете начать сразу с нужного индекса: `for (int index = startIndex; index < length+startIndex; ++index) temp += str[index];`

Comment: Собрать строку из массива символов или использовать StringBuilder или глядите реализацию [Substring](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,882fa7998d6ca35a)

Comment: @tym32167, в реализации используется небезопасное копирование памяти, зачем ТС это смотреть? Он же не плюсы изучает... :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну я же на один, а аж 3 варианта ему кинул, пусть смотрит какой хочет :)

Comment: По поводу "а хочу чтобы код работал для всех случаив": пока в вопросе явного не будут озвучены все случаи -- вопрос нужно будет закрывать, а не играть в телепатов, логично? Продумывайте все кейсы, правьте вопрос, переоткрывайте заново -- будет вам ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего для вас будет интересен метод расширение. Пример кода

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string MySubstring(this string str, int startIndex, int length)
    {
        string temp = string.Empty;
        for (int index = 0; index < str.Length; ++index)
        {
            if (index == startIndex)
            {
                for (int j = index; j < length + index; ++j)
                {
                    temp += str[j];
                }
                return temp;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string template = "привет мир!";
        var result = template.MySubstring(2, 5);
    }
}
```

зы. как заметили в одном из комментариев, чтобы не потерять много в производительности, следует использовтаь **StringBuilder**

пример кода с созданием метода в классе Program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string template = "привет мир!";
        var result = MySubstring(template, 2, 5);
    }

    static string MySubstring(string str, int startIndex, int length)
    {
        string temp = string.Empty;
        for (int index = 0; index < str.Length; ++index)
        {
            if (index == startIndex)
            {
                for (int j = index; j < length + index; ++j)
                {
                    temp += str[j];
                }
                return temp;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

зы. производительный(и правильный) метод будет выглядеть так

```
    static string MySubstring(string str, int startIndex, int length)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);

        for (int index = startIndex; index < length + startIndex; ++index)
        {
            sb.Append(str[index]);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```